# How to convert a dataframe into named list and remove the NA too

Tags: r, list

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(cell_type = c("Adipocytes", "Astrocytes", "B cells"
), V1.x = structure(c(NA, 14L, 4L), .Label = c("alb", "beta-s", 
"ccr2", "cd74", "cx3cr1", "fosb", "gria2", "gzma", "lck", "myh6", 
"plp1", "ptgs2", "s100a9", "slc1a2", "ttr"), class = "factor"), 
    V2.x = structure(c(7L, 18L, 8L), .Label = c("1500015o10rik", 
    "apold1", "ccl5", "cd74", "coro1a", "cybb", "fabp4", "h2-aa", 
    "hpx", "mag", "ms4a4b", "myh7", "s100a8", "selplg", "slc4a1", 
    "smoc2", "snap25", "xist"), class = "factor"), V3.x = structure(c(8L, 
    1L, 6L), .Label = c("bcan", "coro1a", "crispld2", "csf1r", 
    "emcn", "h2-ab1", "itgb2", "lpl", "mal", "mt3", "myl2", "ngp", 
    "nkg7", "rhd", "s100a8", "serpina1a", "slc1a2", "tyrobp"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
   cell_type   V1.x  V2.x   V3.x
1 Adipocytes   <NA> fabp4    lpl
2 Astrocytes slc1a2  xist   bcan
3    B cells   cd74 h2-aa h2-ab1
```

What I want to do is to convert them as a list of named vector with `cell_type` as name, and I also want to remove the `<NA>`, yielding:

```
$Adipocytes
fabp4    lpl

$Astrocytes
slc1a2  xist   bcan

$`B cells`
cd74 h2-aa h2-ab1
```

How can I achieve that?
I'm stuck with this: `lapply(group_split(df, cell_type), as.vector)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `split` to split based on `cell_type` and then use `lapply` to remove `NA` values

```
lapply(split(df[-1], df$cell_type), function(x) x[!is.na(x)])

#$Adipocytes
#[1] "fabp4" "lpl"  

#$Astrocytes
#[1] "slc1a2" "xist"   "bcan"  

#$`B cells`
#[1] "cd74"   "h2-aa"  "h2-ab1"
```

---

A variation using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be to use `group_split` to split based on `cell_type`, `discard` `NA` values from each list and assign names using `setNames`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  group_split(cell_type, keep = FALSE) %>%
  map(~discard(flatten_chr(.), is.na)) %>%
  setNames(df$cell_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
setNames(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) unname(x)[complete.cases(x)]), df[[1]])
#$Adipocytes
#[1] "fabp4" "lpl"  

#$Astrocytes
#[1] "slc1a2" "xist"   "bcan"  

#$`B cells`
#[1] "cd74"   "h2-aa"  "h2-ab1"
```